Java how to know if char consists of two codepoints?
Java stores a character as an UTF-16 encoded codepoint(s). So when a character which needs two codepoints is stored it is split into two characters. So when I print the following string this happens:
(Tested with random two codepoint long character: https://codepoints.net/U+1230D)
String s = "\uD808\uDF0D";
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(s.length());
System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
System.out.println(s.charAt(1));

Output:

2
?
?

As expected it prinst garbage when only printing one part of the character.
But how can I now know that a character consists of two codepoints?
I guess by a special bit set in the first or second part?
I think the explanation is somewhere in here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF) but I don't really understand it.

A char never consists of two codepoints. Did you mean the other way around?

Are you asking how to tell if a char is part of a surrogate pair? If so, see methods like Character#isHighSurrogate(char), Character#isLowSurrogate(char), and Character#isSurrogatePair(char,char).

also check some additional methods Character#isSurrogate(char), Character#charCount(int), Character#codePointAt(CharSequence, int), String#offsetByCodePoints(int, int) and many more depending of exactly what you need

I wonder how this question can be considered a duplicate of "Print unicode character in java"?? --- BTW title: "if char consists of two codepoint" - actually the other way around: if one codepoint consists of two chars (in given example)

I suggest you first understand codepoint and  Combining character. A character can not consist of two codepoints. If you want to know whether a character has a surrogate pair, you can simply check its length e.g. "".length(), "\uD808\uDF0D".length() etc.

Avoid char
The char type has been essentially broken since Java 2, legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, char is physically incapable of representing most of the 154,998 characters defined in Unicode.
Do not use char. Do not call String#length. Do not call charAt.
Code point
Learn to use only code point integer numbers to work with individual characters.
You will find code point related methods on various classes, such as String, StringBuilder, and Character.
int[] codePoints = “".codePoints().toArray() ; // One character, one code point. But `String#length` reports `2`. So don’t call `String#length`. 

Be aware that what the human reader perceives as a single character may be composed of multiple code points. In this next example we use a COMBINING ACCENT ACUTE (code point: U+0301 hex, 769 decimal) as the fifth code point.
String x = "cafe\u0301" ;

Alternate syntax:
String x = new StringBuilder( "cafe" ).appendCodePoint( 769 ).toString() ;

The naïve reader perceives four characters, but the text is actually composed of five code points. Get the count of code points:
long countCodePoints = x.codePoints().count() ; 

See this code run at Ideone.com.

café
5

See each of the code points.
x.codePoints().forEach( System.out :: println ) ;

When run:
99
97
102
101
769

See the name of each code point.
x.codePoints ( ).mapToObj ( Character :: getName ).forEach ( System.out :: println );

LATIN SMALL LETTER C
LATIN SMALL LETTER A
LATIN SMALL LETTER F
LATIN SMALL LETTER E
COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT


Thanks very much for actually providing a useful answer.

For completeness, the characters from human reader’s perspective can be iterated like Pattern.compile("\\X").matcher("cafe\u0301 ") .results().forEach(mr -> System.out.println(mr.group()));
